# How to display text in alertbox in specific manner

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How to display alertbox message in specific manner ,here is my text format to display in alertbox .,[image: Textformat]

how to display text in alertbox as shown in snip shot above ,suggestions please.

Comment: try to create a custom dialog.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setBackgroundColor(0xffeeeeee);
tv.setTextColor(0xff000000);
tv.setTextSize(22);
SpannableStringBuilder b = new SpannableStringBuilder();
b.append("some text here, it will be placed in several lines and then you will see the numbers:\n");
Object lms = new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(12, 28);
int start = b.length();
b.append("1. first of all it should work and this text should be nicely indented\n");
b.append("2. if not, some bugs exist\n");
b.setSpan(lms, start, b.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
lms = new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(-12);
start = b.length();
b.append("and this is the rest of the text");
b.setSpan(lms, start, b.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(b);
setContentView(tv);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Custom Dialog` for accomplishing this task. Make a layout as in your picture , using `Relative or Linear Layout` And set that layout to the `Dialog`.

Here is the example for achieving this 
[Android Custom Dialog Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your button click:

**Custom Dialog:**

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
            dialog.setTitle("Title...");


            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text2);
                    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text3);
            text1.setText("Your Header");
                    text2.setText("1. body");
                    text3.setText("2. body");

 Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButton);

            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        dialog.show();
```

**custom.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your header"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1. body1"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2. body2"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

<Button android:id="@+id/dialogButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Close"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```